# iOS CLocationUpdates in 10.3.1 drop outs

Tags: ios, core-location

Since I updated my test device to 10.3.1 I see an unusual unreliable behavior of CoreLocation updates. Background updates worked fine, but now I do see several minutes with no location updates.

Example: (watch the gap between 7:52 and 7:55)

```
"DidUpdateLocation(456):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.32941864,+7.32525473> +/- 10.00m (speed 12.89 mps / course 268.59) @ 11.04.17, 07:52:33 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(457):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.32945728,+7.32498240> +/- 10.00m (speed 15.14 mps / course 274.22) @ 11.04.17, 07:52:34 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(458):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.32949496,+7.32475064> +/- 10.00m (speed 15.72 mps / course 276.33) @ 11.04.17, 07:52:35 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(459):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.32913876,+7.31447465> +/- 20.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11.04.17, 07:54:01 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(460):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33095244,+7.31326157> +/- 3848.52m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:14 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(461):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33135000,+7.31427845> +/- 3848.52m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:14 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(462):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33164169,+7.31502036> +/- 3848.53m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:14 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(463):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33185754,+7.31555743> +/- 3848.75m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:15 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(464):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33201442,+7.31595280> +/- 3848.87m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:16 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(465):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33251218,+7.30468715> +/- 165.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:17 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(466):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33251444,+7.30467202> +/- 165.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:18 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(467):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33281479,+7.30472224> +/- 200.00m (speed 10.76 mps / course 355.43) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:19 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(468):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33300525,+7.30473463> +/- 200.00m (speed 10.76 mps / course 355.43) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:20 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(469):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33316824,+7.30473717> +/- 30.00m (speed 14.44 mps / course 349.80) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:21 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(470):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33309477,+7.30483197> +/- 50.00m (speed 16.59 mps / course 352.62) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:22 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(471):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33345976,+7.30459652> +/- 10.00m (speed 14.98 mps / course 349.45) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:23 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
"DidUpdateLocation(472):" 1 item(s), [0]:<+50.33364132,+7.30456316> +/- 10.00m (speed 14.47 mps / course 350.86) @ 11.04.17, 07:55:24 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
```

It looks as it CL switched from using GPS hardware to cell tower (accuracy jumps to "+/- 3848.52m", speed to "-1") and back. The app run in background, but had plenty of remaining background time (*UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining*).

BTW: this remaining background time (172 seconds) did not change between the gap. Before and after the gap there was the usual decrements every second.

My location update settings are the following:

```
"initializeLocationTracking()"): .pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically == false
"initializeLocationTracking()"): .allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates    == true
"initializeLocationTracking()"): .distanceFilter  == -1.0
"initializeLocationTracking()"): .activityType    == .fitness
"initializeLocationTracking()"): .desiredAccuracy == 10.0
```

Does anybody else see the same behavior? Has someone a good explanation?

Comment: Hey Hardy, did you try to file a bug with Apple? If yes, I wonder what they told you. I submitted a bug report about a week ago (#34367832), no response so far.

Comment: Hallo Alex, No I didn't file a report. After a lot of intense testing, I think it is related to some kind of aggressive battery management. It only apearse if the device has woken up by a location event. But for this situation IOS "ranked" the demand for new locations lower than "longer battery life".

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too fast ...  This follows the idea of "user has anyway no knowledge of the location update (all in background), so location updates can not be soo important". As such it works "as designed". Not satisfying, but understandable.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, Hardy. Obviously they are trying to extend battery life. But this behavior must be documented, otherwise it is a serious breach of API contract.